# JS- Inner and Outer Catch

Tags: typescript, promise

Say I have 2 `catch`s. like so:

```
try {
axios.get('https://example.com', {})
  .then(function (responseOne: any) {
    return axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {})
  }).then(function (responseTwo: any) {
    return axios.put('https://example.com', {}, {})
  }).then(function (responseThree: any) {
    return axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {})
  }).then(function () {
    reply.send
  }).catch(error) => {}
} catch(errorOuter) => {}
```

From what I've read - it would only go into the outer catch the first axios call was `await axios.get(...)`. Is this correct? What if each of the `then` blocks was also `await`?

If the code remains as is, would it only ever go into the inner catch. And if so, I guess I can remove the outer catch.

Comment: I'd switch to the `async`/`await` pattern. Almost unreadable otherwise. At that point, you'd need just one `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it would only go into the outer catch the first axios call was await axios.get(...). Is this correct?

Not really.

The promise returned by `axios.get('https://example.com', {})` is handled by `then`, and the same is true for the subsequence promises up until the end of `catch`.

If you added `await` at the start of line 2 then you would be awaiting the promise returned by the call to `catch()`.

The callback you pass to `catch()` captures and discards any exception anywhere on that chain of promises.

Thus it would never go into the outer catch.

---

> If the code remains as is, would it only ever go into the inner catch. And if so, I guess I can remove the outer catch.

Technically, yes, but you'd be better off getting rid of `then` and just using `await`. It would make the code easier to follow.

```js
try {
    await axios.get('https://example.com', {});
    await axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {});
    await axios.put('https://example.com', {}, {});
    await axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {});
    reply.send;
} catch (e) {
    // do something with e
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. And I need the response from each step so I guess I could just assign the await then use in step 2. For example:
```let respOne = await axios.get('https://example.com', {});
let respTwo = await axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {//use respOne here});```

Comment: Yes, that's how `await` works.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example I don't see any way that the "outer" `catch` (the one matched to the original `try`) would be invoked, unless somehow Axios threw an exception just trying to *invoke* its asynchronous operation.

The chained promises for each subsequent operation will eventually land in the chained call to `.catch()` in that `Promise` if something failed.  But *the whole chain* is one big asynchronous operation, and that overall `try` block completes and exits before that operation ever gets anywhere.

(That is... If you were to add a `console.log` statement immediately after all of the code shown, you'd see that statement is reached *before* any of the AJAX operations have returned.)

The "outer" try/catch in this case would only be useful if you switched from chaining `.then()` callbacks to using `await`.  For example:

```
try {
  const responseOne = await axios.get('https://example.com', {});
  const responseTwo = await axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {});
  const responseThree = await axios.put('https://example.com', {}, {});
  // etc.
} catch(errorOuter) {
  // handle error
}
```